# Warning: fopen(): Filename cannot be empty

Tags: php, wordpress, fopen, fwrite, is-empty

I am using a WP theme which is great. there is an issue with it as it always displays an error as regarding these lines `$handle   = fopen($tmpfname, "w+");`, and this: `if( fwrite($handle, "<?php\n" . $phpCode))`, indicating that the file is empty.

What am I to do? The errors I have added below.

```
function setup_theme_temp($phpCode)
        {
            //create a temporary filename
            $tmpfname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "setup_theme_temp");
            //open the new file URL
            $handle   = fopen($tmpfname, "w+");
            if( fwrite($handle, "<?php\n" . $phpCode))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                $tmpfname = tempnam('./', "setup_theme_temp");
                $handle   = fopen($tmpfname, "w+");
                fwrite($handle, "<?php\n" . $phpCode);
            }
            fclose($handle);
            include $tmpfname;
            unlink($tmpfname);
            return get_defined_vars();
        }
```

Error

```
Warning: fopen(): Filename cannot be empty in 
Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

Comment: PHP probably fails to create a temporary file with `tempnam()`. Check your PHP configuration and directory permissions.

Comment: Thanks. Solved. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31114948/php-error-fopen-filename-cannot-be-empty-in